# Finding a blade variable inside string

Tags: laravel, laravel-5.3

I'm passing a $emailtemplate variable into a view.

This $emailtemplate is a model with the following properties

```
(string) 'from_name', (string) 'from_email', (string) 'subject', (string) 'body', (string) 'email_type', (integer) 'status'
```

User's can create new instances of the $emailtemplate via a FORM on the site, where they can populate each of the fields above.

An example of the body as populated by users into the FORM would be exactly the following line (yes users will be writing HTML code into the form to be stored in the body property of the $emailtemplate):

```
<strong>Dear {{$user->first_name}} </strong>
```

I have created a view which will allow users to 'Preview' the email. The variables $emailtemplate and $user are both passed to the view (for the case of the preview the $user = Auth::user())

*resources/views/emails/preview.blade.php*:

```
{!! $emailtemplate->body !}}
```

This 'preview' view correctly renders the strong styling however does not identify the blade variable reference as it is stored within a literal string.

i.e. the HTML that is rendered is exactly

**Dear {{$user->first_name}}**

What is going wrong here? I want to allow Users to develop their own email templates via a form. I am passing both the $emailtemplate and $user into the view however because the $emailtemplate->body is a string datatype Laravel does not recognise the use of the blade variable between the parenthesis.

How can I fix this?

Thanks for your help

Comment: show the clouse that you trans variables to the view.

Comment: Please consider marking answer as accepted if it helped you.

Answer (score 0):

You can't do this since Laravel wont Re-render the blade output, to see and replace any variables that is injected by another variable!

Take a look at https://github.com/TerrePorter/StringBladeCompiler

So, you should evaluate the user defined template first, e.g.

```
<strong>Dear {{$user->first_name}} </strong>
will become:
<strong>Dear Foo </strong>
```

This evaluated `<strong>Dear Foo </strong>` will be stored in `$evaluatedTemplate`

Then you can use this in your main blade template:

```
{!! $evaluatedTemplate !!}
```

Also see: 
https://github.com/Flynsarmy/laravel-db-blade-compiler

Comment: Thanks very much for your answer :)

Comment: Is there any other way of doing this? Can I run a $view object back through blade?

i.e. I retrieve the first run of the view via

    $view = View::make('email_templates.preview', $data);

then pass the $view object back through like

    $view2 = View::make($view, ['first_name','Jordan']);
    return $view2;

Comment: @user3502651 no, this is impossible as I know, and this is why people are writing some custom packages to make this possible. you can output to file using `toString` but you can not input from a variable.